# Is it possible to let a user choose the color of their square (game component) in an html/js game before they play?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Sorry if the title is unclear. I am making a simple HTML/JS/CSS game and I use a square as the player sprite. I was wondering if it is possible to have the user choose the color of their square before they play the game, so that they can customize it. I will paste my code for the game currently. I was also wondering if it's possible to make a start screen for the game? Instead of having it load when the page loads.

```js
var myGamePiece;
    var myObstacles = [];
    var myMusic;
    
    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "purple", 10, 120);
     myObstacles = [];
        myObstacle  = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);  
        myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
        myGameArea.start();
    }
    
    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
      this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        },
        stop : function() {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }
    function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedX = 0;
        this.speedY = 0;    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;    
        this.update = function() {
     ctx = myGameArea.context;
            if (this.type == "text") {
                ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
            } else {
                ctx.fillStyle = color;
                ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            }
        }
        this.newPos = function() {
            this.x += this.speedX;
            this.y += this.speedY;        
        }    
        this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
            var myleft = this.x;
            var myright = this.x + (this.width);
            var mytop = this.y;
            var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var otherleft = otherobj.x;
            var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
            var othertop = otherobj.y;
            var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
            var crash = true;
            if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
                crash = false;
            }
            return crash;
        }
    }
    
    function updateGameArea() {
        var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
                myGameArea.stop();
                return;
            } 
        }
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
        if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
            x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
      minHeight = 20;
      maxHeight = 200;
      height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
      minGap = 50;
      maxGap = 200;
      gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
            myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
      myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
            myObstacles[i].x += -1;
            myObstacles[i].newPos();
      myObstacles[i].update();
        }
     myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
        myScore.update();
        myGamePiece.newPos();    
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
    function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
    this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
    this.sound.pause();
    }
    }
    function restart() {
    myGameArea.stop();
    myGameArea.clear();
    startGame();
    }
    function everyinterval(n) {
        if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
      return false;
      }
    function moveup() {
        myGamePiece.speedY = -1; 
    }
    
    function movedown() {
        myGamePiece.speedY = 1; 
    }
    
    function moveleft() {
        myGamePiece.speedX = -1; 
    }
    
    function moveright() {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 1; 
    }
    
    function clearmove() {
        myGamePiece.speedX = 0; 
        myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
    }
```

```css
 p {
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Blockbound</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    
    </head>
    <body onload="startGame()">
    
    <div style="text-align:center;width:480px;">
      <button onmousedown="moveup()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="moveup()">UP</button><br><br>
      <button onmousedown="moveleft()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="moveleft()">LEFT</button>
      <button onmousedown="moveright()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="moveright()">RIGHT</button><br><br>
      <button onmousedown="movedown()" onmouseup="clearmove()" ontouchstart="movedown()">DOWN</button>
      <div style="text-align:right;width:480px;">
      <button onmousedown="restart()">RESTART</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to Blockbound!</p>
    <p>Instructions: Use the buttons to control the purple square. Get the highest score you can without colliding with the obstacles!</p>
    <p>Game made by Sebastian Latham</p>
    <p>HIGH SCORES:</p>
    <p>Broteam123: 13978</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes; it's certainly possible.  What have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: I am very new to coding, and this is my real first project, I guess you could call it. I wanted professional answers so I came here to see what I could get. I am not very familiar with the way javascript works but so if anyone/you could provide me some example code or some code I can add and try experimenting with, that would be great..this code is basically examples from sites, edited into a way I want to make it. I have some other things I want to add as well but this is what I wanted to start with. Any tips?

Comment: No offence, but if you do not even familiar with the basics of javascript you shouldn't just jump into coding and ask for professional help with a little bit more sophisticated things than basic. No matter how good the answer won't help you or anyone who would come to this page in the future. Pick a course (there are plenty of them for free) and learn the basics.

Comment: I have to agree with you. I should of thought this through better and in the future I will do this. I really should of become more familiar with javascript, etc. Thanks for the feedback anyhow and I will apply this. I'm just so excited to learn things but I should not have jumped in to something so complex so fast. Sorry, I will improve and act better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked 2 questions here.

Regarding the sprite colour, I think that learning about javascript function parameters would be very valuable. [Here's some info on that](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

You can see that the game piece sprite is determined in the **myGamePiece** variable which is holding a component function with 5 parameters.

```
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, 'purple', 10, 120);
```

This variable is within the startGame() function so if you passed a string argument of the colour to the startGame function and referenced it into the new component, you could see it working. I'd change the startGame function from having no parameters to this:

```
function startGame(chosencolour) {


        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, chosencolour, 10, 120);
    myObstacles = [];
    myObstacle  = new component(10, 200, "green", 300, 120);  
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}
```

A simple way to demonstrate this would be to use buttons that launch the game instead of how it's currently being launched through the html body onload.

```
<button onClick="startGame('red')">Red Sprite</button>
```

This will put you in the right direction towards having users being able to use their own sprite.

Regarding your second question about a starting screen, remove the startGame function from the body onload in your html, create a new div like

```
<div id="startscreen"></div>
```

with the colour sprite options and then change the styling of the startscreen div to display:none from within the startGame function.

```
document.getElementById('startscreen').style.display = 'none';
```

There's a lot to learn from the code you're starting out from, so do consider looking up more info on [javascript functions.](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Comment: Very good in depth answer. Sorry about asking 2 questions at once however there is just so much I want to add and I'm very excited to learn. Thank you for taking the time to give me a detailed answer, I will definitely take more time to look at this

Comment: Just to let you know. The use of onclick is discouraged nowadays by modern practices. Try using `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: I wanted to ask one more question. I have created the individual buttons, however the sprite appears black. Why is this??

Answer (score 0):

Both of these questions are most definitely possible. It would require you to design the start screen itself and to make a button or something on that start screen that calls a function that'd load the game.

As for making the player be able to choose their color, it'd require you to designate a section of the game(probably in settings) to where they can open up a HTML color wheel, or however you choose to display colors. Then, make it save what the player chooses into their settings file(probably where you save their usernames or what have you) and once they close settings or hit apply to then make their square color load the saved value as the new color.

Comment: This is very good information, thank you. I'm fairly new to this but I want game design, web design, etc. as a career one day so I wanted to start with a game, even as small as this. If you are able, could you show me some example code on how I would do these? You don't have to do each if you don't want or copy out a whole project. Just something to get me started.